# Is possible to get usefull exceptions in xamarin.forms + F#?

Tags: exception, f#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm testing the viability of use Xamarin.Forms + F# for a side project. When things work, is great. But when the code have a problem, ALWAYS I get this exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for <StartupCode$BestSellerPOS>.$Forms
```

And not matter why the error happened. So, I need to step-by-step each line, from the start, just to see what happened.

*This time* this is the full exception (This have happened several times, but I don't record earlier errors to see if is the same exact backtrace... only remember that is the same initial exception):

```
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for <StartupCode$BestSellerPOS>.$Forms ---> System.Exception: Missing or incorrect header for method .cctor
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at BestSellerPOS.Forms.get_mainForm () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at BestSellerPOS.App.get_FormDocs () [0x00000] in /Users/mamcx/Proyectos/BestSeller/BestSellerNET/Core/App.fs:7
  at BestSellerPOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0001c] in /Users/mamcx/Proyectos/BestSeller/BestSellerNET/iOS/AppDelegate.fs:16
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:62
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:46
  at BestSellerPOS.Main.main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/mamcx/Proyectos/BestSeller/BestSellerNET/iOS/AppDelegate.fs:23
```

I have the last versions of everything, on yosemite.

P.D:

I have setup a blank solution with minimal coding, and force in the startup a divide by zero error. Still not get that error, instead a generic message.

Then create another black solution, this time, without the shared project, exactly as provide by the xamarin ios template. This give a good exception, and point to the exact location!

Answer (score 0):

In F#, you get `TypeInitializationException`, when an exception occurs during `module` intialization. This suggests, that somewhere a `let`-bound value explodes. Without seeing the code, it will be difficult to say exactly where it happens.

But the solution usually means changing from a `let` bound value that is executed during initialization, to a function by adding say `()` on a few crucial places and deferring the execution until a more meaningful time where you can handle the exception as needed. Alternatively, you can declare your value as `lazy` and defer execution using that.

Generally, I'd advise against exceptions during `module` initialization, as the moment when the module initialization happens is not simple to predict.

Comment: Hi, yes I found that. I removed all traces of that kind of functions, still get the error. However, the questions is: exist a way to know what exactly cause the exception, because shooting in the dark is not good. Is this a problem of F#, Mono, Xamarin?